# JQuery Get the height of dynamically added pictures before appending into the DOM

Tags: jquery, image, dom, dynamic-content

The question is pretty straight forward, my intention is to, later on, append the pictures into 3 different columns depending on the used vertical space by the pictures that is the reason i need to know the height of the pictures.

The following is my script

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

 //----------------------------------image feed-----------------------------
//random generator
    //array length 
        arr = []; arr.length = 94; //Number of images
        $.each(arr, function(i,v){v = i+1; arr[i] = v;});
        //random
        var i= arr.length, j, temp;
        while(--i > 0){
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            temp = arr[j]; arr[j] = arr[i]; arr[i]=temp;
            };
//end of image feed and random

//load all thumbnails

    window.imagesThumb = [];
    $.each(arr, function(i,v){
        myImagethumb = $(new Image()).attr({
            "src":"img/pictures/thumbnails/img"+v+".jpg",
            "id":v,
            "class":"image"
        }); 
        imagesThumb[i] = myImagethumb; 

    });


//--------------------------------END OF IMAGE FEED-------------------------

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following when you're loading it async:

```
var i = new Image; 
i.src= 'https://YOUR_IMAGESRC'; 
i.onload = function(){ console.log(i.width, i.height) }
```

So basically, with your code, you'd only have to do:

```
myImagethumb.onload = function(){/**...*/}
```

```js
var i = new Image; 
i.src= 'https://media.giphy.com/media/l0HlSF89is7bCAjte/giphy.gif'; 
i.onload = function(){ alert(i.width); alert(i.height) }
```

Comment: can you try a simple jsfiddle? cause I wasn't able to pull it off

Comment: What exactly is the problem with my proposal? I did add a Fiddle now but please explain what you did not understand and what you tried.